# How to add call back when 2 state update at the same time using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How to add call back when more than 2 states update at the same time.
please check bellow code of class component where I add a call back when that states will updated successfully.

```
this.setState({liveMatches: finalMatches, isLoading: false, runningFetch: false, disbleSportsSwitch:false}, ()=> this.startListener());
```

But Now I What to convert this code in hooks inside the functional component.

```
Useeffect(()=>{
  startListener());
},[liveMatches,isLoading,runningFetch,disbleSportsSwitch])
```

Please check is it correct or not ?

Comment: Also consider using `useReducer` if you have multiple related bits of state as seems might be the case from your question.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what you have in the class setup would be:

```
const [liveMatches, setLiveMatches] = useState(/* default value */);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(/* default value */);
const [runningFetch, setRunningFetch] = useState(/* default value */);
const [disbleSportsSwitch, setDisbleSportsSwitch] = useState(/* default value */);

// later
const onSomeEvent = () => {
  setLiveMatches(finalMatches);
  setIsLoading(false);
  setRunningFetch(false);
  setDisbleSportsSwitch(false);
  this.startListener();
};
```

`onSomeEvent` depends on the context of your app. It might be page load or a button click. Its not possible to say from your question

If those 4x pieces of state are closely related (liveMatches, isLoading, etc) you could also consider `useReducer` - but I would start with `useState` until you comfortable with hooks (or if it becomes too complex)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided above will add a callback on every state change.(please provide dependency array correctly)

But you can identify the dependecy causing effect by introducing your custom hook and if 2 or more than 2 found changed then add your callBack